# How can I insert org-capture-templates into a document I'm editing

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have a capture template for TODO items defined as follows

`("t" "todo" entry (file "~/org/refile.org")
             "* TODO %?\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)`

While editing a document, I would like to insert the template where my cursor is. An example foll
ows:

My buffer looks like this:

```
* TODO make a sandwich
    <cursor here>
```

I call my new command, `org-insert-template`.

I am prompted with the available capture templates and choose `[t] TODO`

My buffer now looks like this:

```
* TODO make a sandwich
  * TODO <cursor here>
    :LOGBOOK:
    CLOCK: [2019-05-06 Mon 23:09]--[2019-05-06 Mon 23:09] =>  0:00
    :END:
    [2019-05-06 Mon 23:09]
```

Could you please provide guidance on implementation of `org-insert-template`?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for implementing your own version of this! Just call
`org-capture` with a prefix argument of zero. For example, I bind
`org-capture` to `C-c c`, so to insert a template at point I can use
`C-0 C-c c`.

This features is mentioned in the help for `org-capture`:

> When called with a ‘C-0’ (zero) prefix, insert a template at point.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest working code:

```
("t" "todo" plain       
(function (lambda nil (goto-char  (point))))
"* TODO %?\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
```

Explanation:

- `(function (lambda nil (goto-char (point))))`

  According to the org-capture-template [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html#Template-elements),
  you can use a function that will find the location that you want the capture temptate to be placed.

  `(lambda nil ...)` Creates a lambda function with no arguments

  `(point)` is the current location. `(goto-char (point))` goes to the current location.
- `("t" "todo" plain`

  `plain` means plain text instead of org-entry.
  When using `plain`, it will always capture to the current location. Using `entry` can sometimes insert the entry at the end of the current headline or the end of the file.

Other Notes:

I recommended using customize interface for complex customizations `M-x customize`. It will show you  a list of from options from the [Value Menu].
[image]